# While loop terminal waiting

Tags: python, while-loop

i have a file named `test.py`.

```
test3 = 1000000000
test = 0 
xtest = True 

def enable():
    while xtest:
        test += 1
        if test > test3:
           test3 += test3 * 3
```

And a file named `testit.py`.

```
import test 
test.enable()
```

when i  run python testit.py my terminal stays unused,how i can avoid terminal waiting ?

Comment: Seems like your loop will go on forever ... But if that's what you want, you can probably run `python testit.py &` to put the job in the background (depending on your shell).

Comment: this will eat the entire CPU. You should consider adding a sleep somewhere

Comment: If your terminal doesn't return to the prompt when you expect, you have a problem.

Comment: The only thing this script does is eat cpu. You can make it eat cpu slower by `import time; time.sleep(.01)`. It is unclear to me what your desired result is. What us 'terminal waiting'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is but to me that looks like an infinite loop.
xtest, which is the variable responsible for stopping the loop, is never set to False inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

simple i want to run it in background sorry for my english is not good,
if i want to enabled via shell what must to do ?

```
import cmd
import operator
import test 


class Ec(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = "testshell$ "
    intro = "Welcome to the testshell shell, type `help` to get started."

    def do_test(self, line):
        test.enable()

    #function
    #function 

    def do_help(self, line):
        print """
              test - to enable it 
              +++++++++++++++++++



               """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Ec().cmdloop()
```

when i run it the above i get 
Welcome to the testshell shell, type `help` to get started.
testshell$ when it type test is still waiting and dont return to shell menu

Comment: This looks like it should be part of the question. Please delete it as an answer and instead edit the question to fully explain what you're doing and what's going wrong.